# How to block a commit, if submodules have changed?

Tags: git

Is it possible to block a commit using a pre-commit hook, if:

- Submodules have uncommitted changes
- Submodules have unpushed changes to at least one remote
- Submodules are in a detached head state

Comment: Yes, it's very much possible to block the commit, using pre-commit hook. I mean it's possible to prevent the unwanted commits using git hooks.Have a look at this site, https://jakemccrary.com/blog/2015/05/31/use-git-pre-commit-hooks-to-stop-unwanted-commits/

Answer (score 0):

Search for uncommitted changes: `git submodule -q foreach git status --short`. If there is any output — block commit.

Search for unpushed changes: `git submodule -q foreach git branch --verbose | grep "ahead\|behind"`.

Check for detached HEAD: `git submodule -q foreach git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD`. If there is at least one 'HEAD' in the output — block commit.